# What does this base64 related function do [in Swift]?

Tags: swift

Can someone explain the behavior of the function below? Some have suggested to not use `NSData`. Do you have better alternatives to mention? If the returned value is `Base64Encoded` can I decode on one of the online `encoders/decoders?` Thanks.

```
func stringToData(message: String) -> NSData? {
    let strData = NSData(base64Encoded: message, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters)
    return strData
}
```

Comment: You are taking a string and attempting to return the binary (NSData) format of the data.  Notice this can fail.  There is an Optional return type. This is indicated by the `?`.  This func is using older Swift syntax.  I suggest you look at Swift 4's Codable. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`NSData(base64Encoded:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1410081-init) is documented to attempt to initialize a  data object with the given [Base64 encoded string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)—and return `nil` if it fails. In other words; it decodes a Base64 encoded string as an NSData object.

In Swift, you would likely use the `base64EncodedString()` function and the `Data(base64Encoded:)` initializer on the `Data` type to encode and decode data as Base64 strings, for example like this:

```
let originalData = Data(bytes: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])

let encodedAsBase64String = originalData.base64EncodedString()
// "AQIDBAUGBwgJCgsM"
let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: encodedAsBase64String) // is optional because the decoding can fail
// 12 bytes: <01020304 05060708 090A0B0C>
```